# Multiple SSIS package Execution in a single package

Tags: ssis-2012

Hi I'm creating a single package to load all the packages using execute package task in my project which are encrypted with the password, but package has been failed and I have given the password to all packages in execute package task. Is there any solution to run all the packages in a single package?

I'm using **SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013** for building the project and packages and I'm running these packages on the **SQL Server 2014**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to note:

1. The ProjectLevel protection level should same with the all the packages available under the project.

Ex: If Project X has packages xx and yy. All should have the same protection level for example EncryptAllWithPassword.

2. While referencing the child package with option Project reference in Execute Package task, provide the new password and confirm the new password.

Comment: Do not forget to mark it as answer if it was useful.